# security of input::get and eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, sql-injection

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'state' => 'required',
    'zipcode' => 'required',
    'address' => 'required',
    ],[
    'state.required'=>'state required',
    'zipcode.required'=>'zipcode required',
    'address.required'=>'address required',
    ]);
    $Userdata = Userdata::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->first();
   $userinfo->update(Input::only('state', 'zipcode','address'));
```

Is this secure to sql injection?
I have found that the quotes are stored in the database without escaping
Is direct store input to db is secure?I do not need escape data ?

Comment: No you don't need to manually escape data. Laravel will handle it for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel uses PDO prepared statements, so you don't need to worry about SQL injection unless you don't need raw SQL queried that you don't use in valid way.

Just to add in your code instead of:

```
$userinfo->update(Input::only('state', 'zipcode','address'));
```

you should rather use:

```
 $userinfo->update($request->only('state', 'zipcode','address'));
```

(but it has nothing in common with SQL injection)

Answer (score 0):

the Idea is not how you saved the data. It's about how do you show the data.
read [Laravel blade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade) to know the mechanism of showing using `{{ content }}` and  `{!! content !!}`.
to make sure :
save `<script>alert("test")</script>` and try to show the saved text using two mechanisms